# Is there a syntax error or other error in this Apache site configuration?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I have a Django Gunicorn server running on an Ubuntu VPS at 0.0.0.0:8000, and while there are some problems with it, it appears to be accepting localhost connections. I have the following in my sites-enabled configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pragmatometer.com
    ServerAlias www.pragmatometer.com analyticalnoticeboard.com www.analyticalnoticeboard.com logisticmvc.com www.logisticmvc.com
    ServerAdmin CJSHayward@PObox.com

    DocumentRoot /home/jonathan/classicorthodoxbible.com
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/author.cjshayward.error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/

</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to connect to http://logisticmvc.com/, I get an Apache (not Gunicorn) 500 error page, but nothing new is logged in /var/log/apache2/error.log.

Are the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse appropriate, or could they be causing the problem? I want the domains listed in the .conf file to serve up the content running on the Gunicorn server on 8000.

Comment: look in `author.cjshayward.error.log` not /var/log/apache2/error.log.

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as such and then accept your own answer so this question doesn't hang "in limbo" for eternity. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
[Tue Jan 14 16:38:37.054643 2014] [proxy:warn] [pid 12715] [client 98.253.179.182:58922] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Jan 14 16:38:38.991741 2014] [proxy:warn] [pid 12619] [client 98.253.179.182:58923] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /favicon.ico. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

A search for the error message turned up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475587/setup-mod-proxy-on-apache-http-server , and I'm off to ordinary Django debugging after enabling proxy_http.load.